# iOS - incompatible pointer types

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview

I get an warning:

> incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIImageView' from 'UIView'

with this code:

```
if ([gestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
    curgraphicview = gestureRecognizer.view;
}
```

The code actually work. But in this case, How can I make it so that I don't have warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to cast it to tell the compiler that you are sure it is a `UIImageView`

```
if ([gestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
    curgraphicview = (UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
}
```